# Gimp Scheme scripting: list parameter

Tags: scheme, gimp

I need to select and fill a varying number of rectangles. The coordinates of the rectangles should be given as parameters. Is it possible to give a list as an .scm script parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... unless you use a text parameter/widget, and then parse the coordinates.

If this is not for batch, consider alternative solutions, ask the user to "draw" the rectangles,  as a multiple selection or as a path with several rectangular strokes.

PS: are you aware that you can script Gimp in Python, which is somewhat easier (even if you won't have native support for lists as script parameters)?

Comment: I created my own batch script generator and executor: https://github.com/void4/PyGimpBatchGen since the Gimp-Python documentation is almost 20 years old.